# Remove from list f#

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I've been working this evening with lists in f# (creating, adding, searching etc) and have recently gotten stuck on a list item delete. The code is pretty straight forward.

```
let menu = [("pizza",17);("hotdog",5);("burger", 12);("drink",3);
("milkshake",4)]

//If key is in dictionary , return new dictionary with value removed
//otherwise return dictionary unchanged
let rec remove dict key =
    match dict with
    //if the list is empty, return an empty list
    | [] -> []
    //if the list is not empty and the head meets the removing criteria
    //return a list obtained by reiterating the algorithm on the tail
    //of the list
    | (k,v) :: tl when k = key -> tl :: remove tl key
    //if the list is not empty and the head does not meet the removing criteria
    //return a list obtained by appending the head to a list obtained by
    //reiterating algorithm on tail of the list 
    | (k,v) :: tl -> (k,v) :: remove tl key
```

The error comes from the final line of the function, `| (k,v) :: tl -> (k,v) :: remove tl key`. Apparently, it doesn't recognize `(k,v)` as the head of the list, and instead only sees a tuple with values. It makes sense, I don't know what else I would expect, but the problem is I don't know how to fix it. I tried putting the tuple inside of a list, like `[(k,v)]` but that made things even worse. I even tried `| hd :: tl -> hd :: remove tl key` but I had the exact same issue. Every other function I have written has accepted hd and tl as lists in my pattern matching.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second guard is wrong. You are using the tail twice, and since you are using it in a cons operation as first parameter it doesn't type check (it expects a single element, not a list).

Change it to:

```
| (k,v) :: tl when k = key -> remove tl key
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one other mistake that you are making. It's a conceptual mistake rather than a bug in your code, but it will lead to more bugs unless you understand your mistake. You wrote:

> Every other function I have written has accepted hd and tl as **lists** in my pattern matching.

(Emphasis mine). Your mistake is in thinking that when you write `hd :: tl`, both `hd` and `tl` are lists. You're half right: `tl` is indeed a list in that syntax, but `hd` is a **single item**. Proof:

```
let theList = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
printfn "The list: %A" theList
// Prints "The list: [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]"
match theList with
| [] -> printfn "The list was empty"
| hd :: tl -> printfn "Head was %A and tail was %A" hd tl
// Prints "Head was 1 and tail was [2; 3; 4; 5]"
```

When you use the syntax `hd :: tl` in pattern-matching, it splits the list into the first item (the head) and the rest of the list (the tail). When you use the syntax `hd :: tl` in a normal expression (e.g., everywhere that isn't a pattern match), you are taking a list called `tl` and a *single item* called `hd`, and *prepending* that item to the list, resulting in a brand-new list that has one more item at the front than the previous list did.

The sentence I quoted would have been correct if you had written:

> Every other function I have written has accepted tl as a list and hd as a list item in my pattern matching.

I hope this helps you understand F# lists better!